# ASIFormDataRequest Web Form completion

Tags: iphone, post, asp-classic, asiformdatarequest

I am trying to use ASIFormDataRequest to fill in a web form (ASP I believe) and submit it to a server from iOS.

The form I am trying to fill in is here: http://www.evolution-timecritical.com/shipment.asp

An example of the form is below:

```
<form name="shipment_form" method="POST" action="shipment.asp" onSubmit="return form_check();">
              <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_enquiry">
                <table width="312"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" id="Form table">
                  <tr align="left" valign="middle"> 
                    <td colspan="2"><span class="intro-highlight-text">CONTACT 
                      DETAILS </span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr align="left" valign="middle"> 
                    <td width="106">Company</td>
                    <td width="232"> <input name="company" type="text" class="textfield-height" id="Company" size="20" maxlength="50"> 
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr align="left" valign="top"> 
                    <td width="106">Company Address</td>
                    <td width="232"> <input name="address1" type="text" class="textfield-height" id="Address1" size="20" maxlength="80"> 
                      <input name="address2" type="text" class="textfield-height" id="Address2" size="20" maxlength="80"> 
                      <input name="address3" type="text" class="textfield-height" id="Address3" size="20" maxlength="80"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr align="left" valign="middle"> 
                    <td>Region/Province</td>
                    <td> <input name="region" type="text" class="textfield-height" id="Country" size="20" maxlength="30"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr align="left" valign="middle"> 
                    <td width="106">Postcode</td>
                    <td width="232"> <input name="postcode" type="text" class="textfield-height" id="Postcode" size="20" maxlength="30"></td>
                  </tr>
```

I am using the below code in iOS to attempt to fill in the form:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

int totalDataCount = [completeData count];

for (int i = 0; i < totalDataCount; i++) {
    [request setPostValue:[completeData objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[completeKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
}

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

The loop sets a value for each of the keys in the form, which are stored in NSArrays.

I get a successful request Finished from ASIFormDataRequest, with status code 200 from the server.

However, the server response string is simply the HTML of the web page of the form (http://www.evolution-timecritical.com/shipment.asp).

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong, or how I can fix this.

Thanks